# Why might "auth/twitter"be missing from my NodeJS routes?

Tags: node.js, everyauth

I'm working on a small NodeJS app that uses everyauth (technically mongooseAuth) to talk to twitter to authenticate users.  I've set up the UserSchema per the instructions for mongooseAuth, as well as the user model, and included app.use(mongooseAuth.middleware()) in my app.configure section.

When I click the button for "Sign in with Twitter", it attempts to go to http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter, but this route is missing, according to the error displayed:

```
Cannot GET /auth/twitter
```

As far as I can tell, this url is supposed to be provided by everyauth/mongooseAuth.  I've searched for answers, but nothing so far has been of help.  This app uses express. Ideas?  I am new to NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that using http://localhost:3000 instead of, for example, http://local.host:3000 caused this error.  Using a different auth such as google, this problem no longer occurred.